# Differential operator and multi-index

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes, differential-algebra

By induction it can prove Leibnitz rules

$\displaystyle D^\alpha(fg)=\sum_{|\beta| \leq |\alpha|} \binom{\alpha}{\beta} D^\beta f D^{\alpha - \beta} g$

from the book where I'm studying, it says that by Leibniz rules follows

$\displaystyle D^\alpha (fu) = f D^\alpha u + \sum_{0 < |\beta|\leq |\alpha|} C_{\beta} D^\beta f D^{\alpha -\beta} u$

where $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ and $f \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$

I can not understand where it comes out this last formula, probably follow through distributional derivative?

Comment: A proof by recurrence (with respect to $|\alpha|$) should do the trick. Note that nobody asks the exact form of $C_\beta$.

Comment: I think the problem is to understand why $C_\beta$ depends only on $\beta$. Differently, in another book if $P(D)=\sum_{0< |\alpha| \leq m} a_\alpha D^\alpha$, then $P(D)(\varphi u)= \varphi P(D)u + \sum_{0<|\alpha| \leq m} P_{(\alpha)}(D)(D^\alpha \varphi u)$, where $P_{(\alpha)}(D)$ is differential operator of order $<m$ @TZakrevskiy

Comment: In fact, in the case of $P(D)$, this book, he says to proceed by induction on $|\alpha|$. Okay, I believe it,